# Spool space error when inserting large result set to table

Tags: teradata, sql-insert, database-cursor, spool

I have a SQL query in teradata that returns a results set of ~160m rows in (I guess) a reasonable time: dependent on how good a day the server is having it runs between 10-60 minutes.

I recently got access to space to save it as a table, however using my initial query and the "insert into " command I get error 2646-no more spool.

query structure is

```
insert into <test_DB.tablename> 

with smaller_dataset as
    (
    select
        *
    from
        (
        select
            items
            ,case items
        from
            <Database.table>
        QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A,B ORDER BY C desc , LAST_UPDATE_DTM DESC) = 1

        where 1=1
        and other things
        
        ) T --irrelevant alias for subquery
    QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A, B ORDER BY C desc) = 1)
, employee_table as
    (
    select 
        items
        ,max(J1.field1) J1_field1
        ,max(J2.field1) J2_field1
        ,max(J3.field1) J3_field1
        ,max(J4.field1) J4_field1
        
    from smaller_dataset S
    self joins J1,J2,J3,J4
    
    group by
        non-aggregate items
    )

select 
    items
    case items
    
from employee_table
;
```

How can I break up the return into smaller chunks to prevent this error?

Comment: What's the Primary Index of "test_db.tablename"? Maybe the spool is just skewed.

Comment: @Fred the primary key is a ROW_ID field though I'm unsure how that is generated.

Comment: Primary Key is not equivalent to Primary Index. If you do `SHOW TABLE test_db.tablename`, what does it say is Primary Index? And how are the values for that column or combination of columns distributed?

Comment: @Fred 
UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX ( ROW_ID )

ROW_ID BIGINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
           (START WITH 1 
            INCREMENT BY 1 
            MINVALUE -999999999999999999 
            MAXVALUE 999999999999999999 
            NO CYCLE),

Comment: So the database likely is trying to materialize a second copy of the data in spool with the ROW_ID added, before the merge into the target table. If it's a skewing issue, you might try adding `HASH BY RANDOM` clause at the end of your INSERT/SELECT. Or it's possible you just don't have a high enough spool limit to hold 2 copies at all. Changing to a `NO PRIMARY INDEX` table could avoid creating the second copy. BTW - without knowing your data and the full SQL, it's very difficult to say how you could break up the query into smaller chunks - that's why I'm suggesting more general approaches.